# Fetching data in parallel from mysql using R doParallel or foreach

Tags: mysql, r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I am trying to fetch data in parallel from MySQL database using R. Following code is fetching data one by one and working fine. But I want to speed up the process by sending multiple queries and save it into different variables. Later I will merge timeseries inside the variables.

```
library(RMySQL)
dbConnect(MySQL(), user='external', password='xxxxxxx', dbname='GMT_Minute_Data', host='xx.xx.xxx.xxx')

sqlData <-select TradeTime, Open, High, Low, Close from ad where tradetime between ‘2014-01-01’ and ‘2015-10-20’
data1= dbFetch(sqlData, n=-1)
sqlData <-select TradeTime, Open, High, Low, Close from ty where tradetime between ‘2014-01-01’ and ‘2015-10-20’
data2 = dbFetch(sqlData, n=-1)
sqlData <-select TradeTime, Open, High, Low, Close from ax where tradetime between ‘2014-01-01’ and ‘2015-10-20’
data3 = dbFetch(sqlData, n=-1)

connections <- dbListConnections(MySQL())
for(i in connections) {dbDisconnect(i)}
```

I have tried to fetch data in parallel using following code:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(RMySQL)

fetchData<- function(nInst, inst1, inst2, inst3, inst4, inst5, startDate, endDate, con1){

  inst<-NULL
  sqlData <-NULL

  if(nInst==1)
    inst<-inst1
  else if(nInst==2)
    inst<-inst2
  else if(nInst==3)
    inst<-inst3
  else if(nInst==4)
    inst<-inst4
  else if(nInst==5)
    inst<-inst5

  sqlData <- dbSendQuery(con1, paste0('select TradeTime, Open, High, Low, Close from ', inst, ' where tradetime between \'',  startDate, '\' and \'',  endDate, '\'' ))
  data1 = dbFetch(sqlData, n=-1)
  print(head(data1))

  data1 
}

cluster = makeCluster(5, type = "SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cluster)
mydb <- NULL
clusterEvalQ(cluster, {

  mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='external', password='xxxxxx', dbname='GMT_Minute_Data', host='xx.xx.xxx.xxx')
  NULL
})


allDataList<-foreach(n =1:2, .verbose=TRUE, .packages=('RMySQL')) %dopar% {
  fetchData(n, inst1, inst2, inst3, inst4, inst5, startDate, endDate, mydb)

}
stopCluster(cluster)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb))
```

Sometime code is only fetching data for the first instrument but not for the rest of the instruments.

Please assist if someone know the solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that foreach is auto-exporting the `mydb` variable to the workers, thus defeating the purpose of initializing with it `clusterEvalQ`. Database connections can't be serialized and sent to other machines properly, which is why it's useful to initialize it manually with `clusterEvalQ`. The foreach `.verbose=TRUE` option let's you verify that `mydb` is *not* auto-exported. If it says that it is auto-exported, you need to prevent it.

In your example, you can prevent `mydb` from being auto-exported by simply removing the `mydb <- NULL` statement, but I suggest that you use the foreach `.noexport='mydb'` option to be certain that it's never auto-exported. Here's a stripped-down example that does that:

```
library(doParallel)

fetchData <- function(ignore) {
  mydb
}

cluster <- makeCluster(5, type = "SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cluster)

clusterEvalQ(cluster, {
  mydb <- sample(100, 1) # different value for each worker
  NULL
})

r <- foreach(n=1:2, .noexport='mydb', .verbose=TRUE) %dopar% { 
  fetchData(n)
}
```

In this case, foreach analyzes the `fetchData` function and notices that it's using a variable named `mydb`. Thus, if `mydb` is defined on the master, it will auto-export it unless you tell it not to. That's why I suggest using `.noexport='mydb'` even if it's not defined in the local environment. It makes doubly sure that your function doesn't use a corrupt database connection.